# Webserver Browser Application

Tags: webserver, proxy, browser

Ok so this might sound crazy, but what I want is to be able to go

domain.com/chrome

and have a browser open in my browser.

The purpose is basically a proxy when I'm in a Net-Nanny environment.

Am I crazy? Is this possible?

I know I could do something like PhPvirtualbox >> Console >> Browser, but that requires an OS with a Hypervisor, with an OS with a Browser, and in my case, it would be a nested hypervisor as my server is already running on esXi. Not that it isn't possible! But seems like a lot of meat for something simple.

PS /chrome = proxy passed to another server.

Comment: It sounds like part of your problem is that you are unable to configure proxy server settings on the client, is that right?

Comment: yes sort of, lol, i am working out the details the easy part was configuring noVNC with VNC ... now to ProxyPass w/ SSL

Comment: reading this thread has helped a lot [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721855/trying-to-get-websockify-novnc-to-work-through-a-reverse-proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel confident saying I found a few answers.

In my situation I have a type 1 hypervisor, so I didn't want to use

```
PhPVirtualBox (runs with VirtualBox a type 2 hypervisor)
```

but that would work fine...

Another options is >>

```
 NoVNC + x11VNC + ApacheProxyPass + linux distro
```

This would allow not just a browser, but a whole desktop, which is fine for me, althought just a browser would be all I really need, but the point is the traffic inside the VNC isn't on the local network.

I had issues getting the final configuration working though and moved to my preferred solution which is WAY more specific to my set up, but works great!

```
esxi host >> esxi html5 web plugin >> esxi html5 web plugin remote console >> All served via nginx reverse proxy inside the esxi host.
```

I can now surf the web "from home" anywhere without being logged/net-nannyed etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I got to the same request:
Linux server (openSUSE) + Apache (Tomcat) + Guacamole.

This allows HTTP(S) from anywhere and passing local VNC in Guacamole.
You can then run anything you have on the server, including a browser.

No need to change any settings on the client or to run any client software other than a browser.